# MetaMap java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, nlp, heap-memory, uima

We keep encountering a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error when running MetaMap (with Java API and UIMA wrapper).

Unfortunately, the logs are not very informative, so we don't know which file it's puking on.

In the past, we've had issues with MetaMap creating huge circular annotations when it's encountered the pipe (`|`) symbol. However, the file set we're using ([MIMIC notes](https://mimic.physionet.org)) don't contain any pipe symbols. Are there other characters that may be exhibiting similar behavior to the pipe symbol?

We could increase system RAM to circumvent the heap space issue (it's actually not able to use the maximum set heap, which is set to 6 GB, since system RAM is limited), but we would prefer to know what is causing the issue, especially since then the output file size is more manageable.

*** EDIT ***

Just to clarify: We have increased memory resources for the JVM and that does help to actually push the data through (this was tested on a local VM). The problem MetaMap has is that it creates enormous circular annotations that eat up the JVM resources (and on our current system, the OS RAM is not optimal).

As noted in my comment below, we preprocess the files to strip them of any characters that throw errors. The heap space error is kind of annoying though, since unlike for other errors we've encounter (e.g., spaces surrounding a lone period, as in `text . text`), these just throw a parsing error with the text that threw the error. In the case of the pipe symbol, we found it by increasing RAM (on the VM we were initially testing this on) and then looking at the annotations in the UIMA viewer. We were able to identify the problematic files, since the output file size of the XMI with circular annotations is enormous.

We are running some tests on the VM again to see if we can identify the issue, but if anyone has MetaMap experience to help us identify any problem characters or character sequences, that would be desirable.

*** EDIT 2 ***

Memory should not be an issue. We are running the app using `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Xms2G -Xmx6G -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=25 -XX:+UseG1GC'`

there is a fundamental issue with circular annotations we are trying to resolve. This is gobbling up resources and puking.

Comment: Can you temporarily increase RAM size just to make sure that the thing does not run out of memory and then do a memory benchmark?

Comment: We've done that, so I know it works. The issue has to do with circular annotations using up a ton of the JVM's resources. We are preprocessing the files to circumvent these issues. The pipe symbol seems to go nuts in creating circular annotations that consume a ton of heap space, which is why I asked if other similar characters could be doing the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried taking a heap dump at the time the application runs out of memory using the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory JVM arg?  Then you can see what is being held in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was two fold:

There is a UIMA JVM environment variable that needed to be set, as `export UIMA_JVM_OPTS="-Xms128M -Xmx5g"`

And secondly, there is a MetaMap switch that reduces the recursion depth for creating annotations (which goes in the MetaMapApiAE.xml config file):

```
<configurationParameterSettings>
    ... previous settings omitted ...
   <nameValuePair>
     <name>metamap_options</name>
     <value>
       <string>--prune 30</string>
     </value>
   </nameValuePair>
</configurationParameterSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your java app is very probably using to the limit the heap space allocated and it reaches the point where the garbage collector cannot efficiently obtain the necessary heap space.

Considering that your app is using the allocated heap space efficiently, the only option I think you have is to increase the allocated heap space. You can do this busing

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar YourApp.jar
```

However, maybe it is worth analysing how the heap space is used. There are tools that allow you to do this. If using IntelliJ you could try to use VisualVM plugin.

Comment: Memory model was changed for JDK 8 - no more perm gen.  Maybe you need other flags to be set.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add recommendations from oracle [trouble shooting article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)

Exception in thread thread_name: **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

> The detail message Java heap space indicates object could not be
>   allocated in the Java heap. This error does not necessarily imply a
>   memory leak

*Possible causes:*

1. Simple configuration issue, where the specified heap size

   is insufficient for the application.
2. Application is unintentionally holding references to objects, and
   this prevents the objects from being garbage collected.
3. Excessive use of finalizers.

> One other potential source of this error arises with applications that
>   make excessive use of finalizers. If a class has a finalize method,
>   then objects of that type do not have their space reclaimed at garbage
>   collection time

After garbage collection, the objects are queued for finalization, which occurs at a later time. finalizers are executed by a daemon thread that services the finalization queue. If the finalizer thread cannot keep up with the finalization queue, then the Java heap could fill up and this type of **`OutOfMemoryError`** exception would be thrown.

One scenario that can cause this situation is when an application creates high-priority threads that cause the finalization queue to increase at a rate that is faster than the rate at which the finalizer thread is servicing that queue.

Comment: See above for further clarification. This is an issue specific to the program we are using.